# Save custom object array in NSUserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

How can I save custom object array to NSUserDefauls like:

```
class Settings: NSObject {
   var name: String? = ""
   var addresss: [Address] = [Address]()
   var addressSelectedIndex: Int = 0
   ....
}

class Address: NSObject {
   var street: String? = ""
   var city: String? = ""
   ....
}
```

I have added encoder and decoder to the both classes. Getting error at:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
   ....
   if let _addresss = self.addresss { // here
      aCoder.encodeObject(_ addresss, forKey: "addresss")
   }
}
```

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[Address]'

Comment: You don't need to use if let address = self.address, directly use `aCode.encodeObject(address, forKey: "address")` is fine. **if let** only works for checking optional type, but your definition of address is not optional type.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with saving custom objects in `NSUserDefaults`. It's about the Swift error. Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Initializer+for+conditional+binding+must+have+Optional+type%2C+not) before posting your question.

Comment: thanks bubuxu, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addresss` is not an optional property, you initialise it to be an empty array. Therefore it makes no sense to do `nil` check on this property using `if let`.

Your encode function should look the following:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
   ....
   aCoder.encodeObject(addresss, forKey: "addresss")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared

```
var addresss: [Address] = [Address]()
```

`addresss` is not optional, therefore you don't need to use the `if let`.

You should declare it as:

```
var addresss: [Address]?
```